# ¿Cómo se scrap dentro de una tabla html?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, table

Quiero raspar las finanzas yahoo para los datos de texto. Por cualquier teletipo deseo poder raspar los ingresos totales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el ejemplo anterior ver la página de L'Oreal. El código del objetivo asociado es:

```
 <div class="rw-expnded" data-reactid="44" data-test="fin-row">
    <div class="D(tbr) fi-row Bgc($hoverBgColor):h" data-reactid="45">
       <div class="D(tbc) Ta(start) Pend(15px)--mv2 Pend(10px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) Bdends(s) Bdbs(s) Bdstarts(s) Bdstartw(1px) Bdbw(1px) Bdendw(1px) Bdc($seperatorColor) Pos(st) Start(0) Bgc($lv2BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) Pstart(15px)--mv2 Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="46">
          <div class="D(ib) Va(m) Ell Mt(-3px) W(215px)--mv2 W(200px)" data-reactid="47" title="Total Revenue"><span class="Va(m)" data-reactid="48">Total Revenue</span></div>
          <div class="W(3px) Pos(a) Start(100%) T(0) H(100%) Bg($pfColumnFakeShadowGradient) Pe(n) Pend(5px)" data-reactid="49"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="D(tbc) Ta(c) Pstart(6px) Pend(4px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(100px) Miw(156px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor)" data-reactid="50" data-test="fin-col"><span data-reactid="51">29,873,600</span></div>
       <div class="D(tbc) Ta(c) Pstart(6px) Pend(4px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(100px) Miw(156px)--pnclg" data-reactid="52" data-test="fin-col"><span data-reactid="53">29,873,600</span></div>
       <div class="D(tbc) Ta(c) Pstart(6px) Pend(4px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(100px) Miw(156px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor)" data-reactid="54" data-test="fin-col"><span data-reactid="55">26,937,400</span></div>
       <div class="D(tbc) Ta(c) Pstart(6px) Pend(4px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(100px) Miw(156px)--pnclg" data-reactid="56" data-test="fin-col"><span data-reactid="57">26,023,700</span></div>
       <div class="D(tbc) Ta(c) Pstart(6px) Pend(4px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(100px) Miw(156px)--pnclg Pend(10px) Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor)" data-reactid="58" data-test="fin-col"><span data-reactid="59">25,837,100</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="D(b)" data-reactid="60"></div>
 </div>
```

Para tratar de obtener los ingresos totales, hice esto:

```
#This will not run on online IDE 
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

ticker = 'OR.SA'
URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/OR.PA/financials?p={ticker}"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
```

Luego trato de conseguir el artículo después de los ingresos totales:

```
soup.find('span', string='Total Revenue').find_next().text
```

Pero me devuelve `''`.

## Actualizacion.

Para otra teletipo no funciona. Por ejemplo con [MPX.AX](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MPX.AX/financials?p=MPX.AX) obtengo:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Sin embargo hay el Total Revenue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que buscas 29,873,600 porque esta resaltado en la imagen, tienes que recorrer la estructura desde el nodo en el que estés

```py
soup.find('span', string='Total Revenue').parent.parent.next_sibling.text
# '29,873,600'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Sin embargo para otra como [*MPX.AX*](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MPX.AX/financials?p=MPX.AX) no parece que hay `parent`. En efecto, obtengo: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'`

Comment: Con el link de MPX.AX me devuelve '2,889'.  Podrías revisar si el link esta correcto o si la respuesta del request es correcta. Si estas realizando muchas consultas el error podría estar generándose porque estas paginas suelen estar limitadas a un numero cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Si, estoy realizando muchas consultas. Saben como podria retrasar para conseguirlos a todos?